# delete with ajax in admin panel magento

Tags: ajax, magento

I want to perform delete operation with ajax in magento admin panel. I have created my own function `deleteAttrGroupKey()` and put it to controller `GrouppricebackendController.php`. I am trying to access `deleteAttrGroupKey()` function from my template(phtml) file but getting invalid path. code is

```
 jQuery(".deleteAttrKeyId").on("click",function(){
      var baseUrl="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl();?>";
      var idArr=this.id.split("-");
      attrKeyId=idArr[1];
      alert(this.id);
      jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "JSON",
        data :{'id':attrKeyId},
        url :baseUrl+"adminhtml/grouppricebackend/deleteAttrGroupKey",
        complete:function(){alert("completed");
          },
        success:function(event){
          alert("deleted"+event);
          }

        });
    });
```

how can I pass correct url for this ?
Do I need to add deleteAttrGroupKey() function in config.xml ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ajax request like this

```
new Ajax.Request("<?php echo $this->getUrl('adminhtml/grouppricebackend/deleteAttrGroupKey') ?>", {
           method: 'Post',
           parameters: {"id":attrKeyId},
           onComplete: function(transport) {

               alert(transport.responseText);

           }
       });
```

Yes you need to include deleteAttrGroupKey function in config.xml file